# Lazy load jquery plugin slowing down page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lazy-loading

I have a page that uses the lazy load plugin to load a bunch of small images. I have a set of filters that remove elements and add elements. So I'm calling lazy load on all my img elements every time the filter is clicked. When I do this it starts to slow down the page and each time I call the $("img").lazyload(); it gets more bogged down. I tried using unbind before the elements get removed so the new once being appended don't have a y left over events but this stil did nothing.

Anyone know why this might happen. My code source is huge so I can't take one element out to post. So hoping someone ran into this issue before and might have an idea why its happening.

Another issue is I have to call $(window).trigger("scroll"); after I call $("img").lazyload(); in order for the images to load. Is this normal.

Comment: Without code there's not much we can do. Try to produce an example with only the relevant bits... you don't have to provide it ALL, just the general logic that concerns your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I was able to figure out today. See my solution to my question here:

[jQuery LazyLoad plugin slowing down div scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428976/jquery-lazyload-plugin-slowing-down-div-scrolling/17431675#17431675)

quick answer though is lazyload binds an event listener every time you run it on the container to check for the scroll. Unfortunately it doesn't unbind this event before rebinding it and so when you run lazyload over and over again you'll add tons of scroll listeners added to the container. A quick solution is to .unbind('scroll') on  your container before calling lazy load again. The link above has more indepth answer along with some fiddles to see the difference.