# jQuery LazyLoad plugin slowing down div scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lazy-loading

Here is my situation. I have loaded in a couple hundred small icons into a container and lazyload them. When using my page this container gets emptied and has new images appended to it as a user uses the program. Depending on the number of images in the container, running lazy load will eventually slow down the container and make it unresponseive.

```
$('#myul').empty();
$('#myul').append('...couple hundred lazyload images appended here...');
$("#myul img.lazy").lazyload({         
   container: $("#mydiv"),
   skip_invisible : false
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Darksbane/PaQya/

if you click run1 you'll note that it runs just fine. Scrolling in the div is smooth and nothing seems amiss. If you click run1 about 20 or 30 more times youll notice that the div scrolling boggs down to the point of being unusable. Clicking on run100 will run it 100 times and show the issue right away.

Does anyone see what could be causing the page sluggishness. I tried calling .off on all the image elements before calling .empty but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was able to figure this one out. Every time you run lazyload it runs through this code to bind the scroll listener

```
/* Fire one scroll event per scroll. Not one scroll event per image. */
        if (0 === settings.event.indexOf("scroll")) {
            $container.bind(settings.event, function(event) {
                return update();
            });
        }
```

The problem is it doesn't unbind any previous scroll listener it placed on the container before placing the new one. So the simplest solution if you don't want to modify the lazyload js file is to unbind the scroll event on your container before calling lazyload on it a second time. This will cause problems if you have other scroll event listeners on the container as it will blow them all away.

Below is a fiddle showing the difference when unbinding first.
http://jsfiddle.net/Darksbane/2PKKn/2/

To fix this in lazyload you likely need to namespace the event so you can reference it to unbind it later.

This is mildly tested but I think the above code could be modified to:

```
/* Fire one scroll event per scroll. Not one scroll event per image. */

if (0 === settings.event.indexOf("scroll")) {
$container.unbind('.lazyload');
$container.bind(settings.event+'.lazyload', function(event) {
return update();
});
}
```

which will unbind any lazyload events on the container leaving other events alone
http://jsfiddle.net/Darksbane/KTUG4/2/

Comment: Just thought i would comment that this solution made it in to the source code, https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/blob/master/jquery.lazyload.js#L78

Answer (score 1):

Or you could make sure you bind the plugin to images only once. Something like:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
   ...
}).removeClazz("lazy");
```

Comment: That isn't the issue in this case Mika. The problem isn't with the existing images having lazy load called on them again (although that can be aproblem). I delete all existing images so removing the class on them wouldn't help.  The container and the scroll listener is the problem as far as I can tell. See my answer below for the solution I came up with.

Comment: Cool. I will play around with your solution a bit. It should be included in the code. Thanks!